# Can I extract or deduce the effective input form to duplicate the results from an interactive toolbar?

Tags: image-processing, interactive

The interactive toolbars that are available in 10.0+ are very nice for getting images to look the way I want; but the black box functionality is very un-Mathematica-like, and doesn't help me if I want to do the exact same things to groups of images.  Is there any way to use the interactive toolbar but then somehow get it to display the expression it is evaluating behind the scenes?

Comment: Seriously.  These tools are really nice if what I want in a computational program is photoshop lite.  Has anyone been able to dig under the hood a little?  As far as I can tell, the documentation consists of a single link to a video that shows how cool it is.